# Problem while retrieving hidden parameter with CXML text as value from Struts2 Project to Simple JSP project

Tags: struts2, cxml

Am passing a cxml document text from Servlet to  JSP in struts2 and the jsp will submit form BODY onload with action = "to Second Project" also the same cxml text been passed in hidden parameter and its working fine, but when i try receive the value of parameter passed from first Project its in-complete only i have got first 15 characters -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using you are using `<input type="hidden" value="" />` and your parameter also got double quote. Try to user value=''